# Using modules of Python in Pypy [Windows]

Tags: python-2.7, pypy

Is there any way to use the modules I have of the Python 2.7 in Pypy on windows 7 32 bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All pure Python libraries should work. See the [compatibility overview](http://pypy.org/compat.html) for extension modules.